# Javascript Click Function Only Works On First Element

Tags: javascript, function, click

I have a simple click function in Javascript that I am trying to get to work. The issue I am having is that the click function is only working for the first element with the class, where I would like it to fire when you click any elements with the class.

```
const element = document.querySelector('.js-element')
if ( element ) element.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('click');
})
```

Can anyone please advise where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You used `querySelector`. That means you selected a single element and added a listener to that one element. Either use `querySelectorAll` and add a listener to each element, or add a listener to the container (or the body) and use event delegation

Comment: ...then you just need `querySelectorAll()`, you can `.forEach()` on the result.

Comment: because querySelector only select the first one.

Answer (score 9):

> The `querySelector()` method of the Element interface ***returns the first element*** that is a descendant of the element on which it is invoked that matches the specified group of selectors.

To attach event to all the element with class `js-element` you have to select all the element using [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then use loop to iterate and attach event like the following.

Also, you do not need the *if* condition here.

```
const element = document.querySelectorAll('.js-element')
element.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('click');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `querySelectorAll()`

```
 const element = document.querySelectorAll('.js-element');
    if (element.length !== 0) {
      for (var i=0; i<element.length; i++) {
        element[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
          alert('click');
        });
      }
    }
```

> The Element method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I was also wondering how to target elements that are currently hidden ( display:none; ), these are then shown by another click function. It looks like querySelectorAll only targets the visible elements.

Comment: @heady12 `It looks like querySelectorAll only targets the visible elements` - No, it targets all elements that are physically in the DOM, visible or not. If you think it doesn't return hidden elements, create a jsFiddle or similar test sample and `console.log()` the `innerText` of each element or similar inside your loop to see that elements with `display:none` are included. - [**https://jsfiddle.net/qpkt0nuf/**](https://jsfiddle.net/qpkt0nuf/) Change as needed to test your own scenario.